# Results of using a comparison operator in the ORDER BY clause

Tags: mysql, order-by

There is a table x:

```
select * from x;

+------+------+
| a    | b    |
+------+------+
| aaa  | 999  |
| bbb  | 888  |
| ccc  | 777  |
+------+------+
```

What do the following queries do?

```
select * from x order by a < b;
select * from x order by a = b;
select * from x order by a <> b;
select * from x order by a <> b, b;
```

What is the name for this operator?
I have not found anything in the MySQL documentation on this topic.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is common comparison operators.

When comparison is performed then some boolean result is produced. It may be TRUE, FALSE or NULL.

These 3 values are related as

```
NULL < FALSE < TRUE
```

This relation is used for sorting.

For example:

```
select * from x order by a<b;
```

If `a` and/or `b` is NULL then the result of ordering expression (comparison result) is NULL, and such records will be at the beginning of the output.

If `a` less then `b` then the result of ordering expression is TRUE and such records will be at the end of the output.

The records where `a` is greater or equal to `b` will be in the middle.

Answer (score 6):

None of these queries should work at all - they are an abomination. Writing SQL where you can query whether an `INTEGER` is less than, equal to, or greater than a `CHAR(n)/VARCHAR(n)/TEXT/<any_character_field>` is **completely meaningless**!

What a `"REAL"` database server (PostgreSQL in this case) does with such horrors is shown [`here`](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=2e88d0af47e38d262fb1f7830a732845) (sample output from one of the queries is shown):

> ERROR:  operator does not exist: character < integer LINE 1: select *
> from x order by a<b;
> ^ HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might
> need to add explicit type casts.

These queries also fail (praise be!) on every other server on `dbfiddle.uk` except for MariaDB which obviously has a vested interest in being bug-for-bug compatible with MySQL. This is hardly surprising as both servers have had a considerable overlap in their main contributors - [Monty Widenius](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Michael_Widenius) is CTO of MariaDB and was a founder of MySQL and MariaDB is touted as a drop-in replacement for MySQL.

### Explanation of MySQL's behaviour:

MySQL's InnoDB engine has a mechanism for generating IMPLICIT PRIMARY KEYs, even it the dba/dev doesn't declare one!

From [`here`](https://federico-razzoli.com/why-mysql-tables-need-a-primary-key), we have (a quote from MySQL's documentation - linked to in post):

> If the table has no PRIMARY KEY or suitable UNIQUE index, InnoDB
> internally generates a hidden clustered index named GEN_CLUST_INDEX on
> a synthetic column containing row ID values. The rows are ordered by
> the ID thatInnoDB assigns to the rows in such a table. The row ID is a
> 6-byte field that increases monotonically as new rows are inserted.
> Thus, the rows ordered by the row ID are physically in insertion
> order.

Unfortunately,  you can't access this pseudo-column. There are no accessible hidden fields - unlike say with Oracle's server which has a plethora of such fields which one can `SELECT` (see [`here`](https://forums.mysql.com/read.php?10,266667,266883#msg-266883)).

> In InnoDB, if you don't provide a PRIMARY KEY (and...), a hidden
> BIGINT will be used as the PK. But you cannot get at it.

The documentation referred to in the previous link says it's a 6 Byte `INTEGER` and not a BIGINT (which has [`8 Bytes - 64 bit`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17952_01/mysql-5.0-en/integer-types.html) - not relevant to this discussion however).

### Edit:

Another piece of evidence is a post [`here`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49815703/what-is-the-default-order-by-for-a-mysql-innodb-query-that-omits-the-order-by/49826908#49826908) from [`Bill Karwin`](https://stackoverflow.com/users/20860/bill-karwin). He was either **a** or **the** MySQL community manager and, as you can see from his profile, is a fairly big hitter on StackOverflow with > 400,000 points. He says:

> Without a clear ORDER BY, current versions of InnoDB return rows in
> the order of the index it reads from. Which index varies, but it
> always reads from some index. Even reading from the "table" is really
> an index—it's the primary key index.
>
> As in the comments above, there's no guarantee this will remain the
> same in the next version of InnoDB. You should treat it as a
> coincidental behavior, it is not documented and the makers of MySQL
> don't promise not to change it.

Also in that post, he gives examples of how MySQL will behave with different `SELECT`s and `INDEX`es - it's worth reading the entire thread!

So, basically, it appears to be the case that MySQL will sort by the implicit `PK` (which is in `INSERT` order) if there is no other `KEY` field in the `SELECT`! A couple of simple tests[[`1`](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=1db26e90b17003c9701c752cc7018d9a), [`2`]](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=3ae03146c774c569ecfabff22cb00b61) demonstrate this in action (results from first test only, refer to the other one if interested):

```
CREATE TABLE a (b VARCHAR(10), c INT);
INSERT INTO a VALUES ('aaa', 999), ('bbb', 888), ('ccc', 777);
```

and

```
CREATE TABLE x (y VARCHAR(10), z INT);
INSERT INTO x VALUES ('ccc', 777), ('bbb', 888), ('aaa', 999);
```

the run:

```
SELECT * FROM a;
```

Result:

```
b     c
aaa 999
bbb 888
ccc 777
```

This **could** be a simple ASCII sort on the first field. However, now compare this to:

```
SELECT * FROM x;
```

Result:

```
y     z
ccc 777
bbb 888
aaa 999
```

But this is **NOT** an ASCII sort on the first field. There is no PK, therefore it uses an `(implicit) clustered index PK (*)` which sorts by insertion order!

(*) this is the way MySQL does PKs - not all servers do this - I can't, off the top of my head, think  of another system that does this by default. All PKs in MySQL are clustered.

I've rewritten your queries (see test 1) so that you can better see what's happening!

```
select a, b, a = b
from x 
order by a = b;
```

Result:

```
  a  b  a = b
aaa 999     0
bbb 888     0
ccc 777     0
```

Here, the expression `a = b` is ALWAYS false, therefore it sorts by hidden PK which is dependent on INSERT order!

and then:

```
select a, b, a <> b 
from x 
order by a <> b, b;
```

Result:

```
  a   b   a <> b
ccc 777        1
bbb 888        1
aaa 999        1
```

In this second case, `a != b` is ALWAYS true, therefore it sorts by the second (this time `explicitly specified`) field in the ORDER BY which is (`b`)! No need to rely on the implicit PK!

You should be able to figure out the rest from there!

As stated by Bill Karwin referenced above, this is an undocumented feature and should **NOT** be relied upon and can be removed/modified at any time.

There is general agreement in the database community that if you want a given order, then you should specify it in the `ORDER BY` clause and **NOT** rely on undocumented features that could potentially change in future releases!

p.s. welcome to the forum! And a +1 for reminding me about how crap MySQL is!

Comment: *None of these queries should work at all* https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=ef9ca454ef90a91773a4c4beb424d991 *query whether an INTEGER is less than, equal to, or greater than a CHAR(n)/VARCHAR(n)/TEXT/<any_character_field> is completely meaningless!* https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/type-conversion.html *they are an abomination* +100500 ! PS. Why you decide that the column `b` has INT datatype? https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=b2c13b389283febfe04bc9563b3465df

Comment: It was this part of the question that made me think that it wasn't a simple string to string comparison `What is the name for this operator?` - if you check the PostgreSQL error that I posted `operator does not exist` - the OP is (IMHO) looking for a valid `TEXT` (CHAR... &c) type to `INT` comparison when no such thing should exist. To be honest, with MySQL, I wouldn't be surprised to find something like: `In certain cases the query "SELECT 1 + 1;" can give the result "3" - if x, y or z apply AND Jupiter is in alignment with Saturn` - Thanks for the link which shows that 1 + '1' = 2 - classic!

Comment: @Vérace "In certain cases the query "SELECT 1 + 1;" can give the result "3" - if x, y or z apply AND Jupiter is in alignment with Saturn" :-) Still, MySQL has improved a lot in later versions. See https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=3d808c258e8f813c986326f4e525bb47 for a funny example that is no longer possible (AFAIK).

Comment: @Lennart - agreed 100% - MySQL has made enormous strides recently - `<sarcasm>Why now, they even have CHECK constraints - only 28 years after the standard mandated them!</sarcasm>` - :-). Seriously though, my first statement does stand - progress has/is undoubtedly been/is being made - my guess in large part because Oracle/MySQL don't have a choice with the power and flexibility of other F/LOSS systems - still credit where credit is due - they could have made [some | all] of these features available on a "pay-per-view" basis!